# Como fazer a mesma consulta no SQL para variáveis diferentes?

Tags: mysql, python, array, query, loop

Olá. Ainda estou começando no SQL e gostaria de saber como implementar um código que retorne uma tabela com a união de várias consultas diferentes que seriam feitas em forma de loop. A situação é a seguinte: o código do SQL está pronto e nesse código preciso inserir os números de pedido, lojas e caixa do produto a serem analisados. Um mesmo pedido pode estar associado a várias lojas diferentes e cada loja tem um número de caixa diferente. A questão é que da forma que eu estou fazendo, estou obtendo uma tabela que retorna os valores de TODAS as caixas digitadas pelo usuário para todas as lojas. O que eu quero é mostrar somente os valores que estão associados a cada loja/pedido. Acredito que se tivesse uma forma de fazer um loop e usar listas para conter esses valores digitados pelo usuário daria certo, mas não sei o SQL tem essa funcionalidade.

Exemplo para ficar mais claro:

O pedido A pode ter sido feito para as lojas (1,2,3,4,5) e cada loja tem um número de caixa diferente que quero analisar: (caixa 1 --> na loja 1, caixa 2 --> na loja 2, caixa 3 --> na loja 3). Da forma como eu estou fazendo, o programa mostra na tabela gerada os valores relacionados a TODAS as caixas para TODAS as lojas, exemplo: loja 1 que eu gostaria somente de ver resultados referentes a caixa número 1, mostrará os resultados também referentes as caixas 2, 3, etc.

Tô usando um:

WHERE num_pedido in (A,B,C,D)
and num_loja in (1,2,3,4)
and num_caixa in (cx1, cx2, cx3, cx4)

Só que obviamente ele sempre vai retornar todas as lojas e todas as caixas para todos os pedidos e não somente aqueles que estão relacionados. Eu quero pedido A (somente loja 1 que tem caixa igual a cx1), pedido B (somente loja 2 que tem caixa igual a cx2) e assim por diante. Como resolver?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Publique o modelo das tabelas e seus relacionamentos.